# How to do complex join in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have Custom user model and two models, both with ForeinKey to two users at once:

```
class Feature1(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='u1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='u2')

    some field....
    percentage = models.FloatField()

class Feature2(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='us1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='us2')

    some fields...
    property = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and then I retrieve all pairs for particular user with queryset

```
queryset = Feature1.objects.filter(u1=self.request.user).all().order_by('-percentage')
```

but what I need, to have in this queryset data from Feature2 model too (for each particular pair of users, if exists)
and to be able order queryset by 'property' from Feature2

How to do it? I've researched django docs, but without result.

Comment: Have you looked into using `select_related()`?

Comment: Probably that's it, but I do not know how to use it properly. My case is not so simple like in django examples.

Comment: Are you desiring all of the fields in `Feature2` where `user1` in `Feature2` is equal to `user1` in `Feature1` and `user2` in `Feature2` is equal to `user2` in `Feature1`?

Comment: @MattCremeens Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

One try would be to first get all of the `user1s` and `user2s` from the first relation

```
u1 = Feature1.objects.all().values_list('user1', flat=True)
u2 = Feature1.objects.all().values_list('user2', flat=True)
```

and then get the `Feature2` objects from the second relation that match those users

```
queryset = Feature2.objects.filter(user1__in=u1, user2__in=u2).order_by('-percentage')
```

I'd like to also offer an alternative to your database design that I feel will help you query your models more efficiently. Why not change `Feature2` so that it has a `ForeignKey` to `Feature1` like so

```
class Feature2(models.Model):
    feature1 = models.ForeignKey(Feature1, verbose_name="Feature 1")

    ...
```

Then you could join the two this way

```
queryset = Feature2.objects.filter(feature1__in=Feature1.objects.filter(u1=self.request.user)).order_by('-percentage')
```

Comment: This is a nested loop join. Any way to do it more efficiently?

Comment: It's the way, but instead one query, we have many. I would like to do it with one query to db (postgresql in my case).

Comment: I'll have to get back to you. @sudo, I am sure there is a more efficient way, but it's what I came up with off the top of my head.

Comment: @Maxim Koro I've edited my answer in a way that I hope better suits your purposes.

Comment: @ Matt Cremeens This is contrary to the original concept. Each unique pair of users has Feature1 record. Same for Feature2. Although F2 has a meaning only in the presence of F1, record F2 can appear before F1. Anyway, Your way makes sense. I'll think about it. Now I tend to use raw SQL in Django.

Comment: That would certainly be another approach: `Feature2.objects.raw("SELECT  ...)`.